# Regular expression to test whether a string consists of a valid real number in base 10

Tags: regex, parsing

Examples:

```
"1"     yes
"-1"    yes
"- 3"   no
"1.2"   yes
"1.2.3" no
"7e4"   no  (though in some cases you may want to allow scientific notation)
".123"  yes
"123."  yes
"."     no
"-.5"   yes
"007"   yes
"00"    yes
```

Comment: For my purposes, "00" would be a "yes".  I'll add the example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This allows for optional "+" and "-" in front.  And allows trailing or initial whitespace.

```
/^\s*[+-]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.\d+)\s*$/
```

Comment: using \b instead of \s* may be slightly more efficient

Answer (score 4):

There are several alternatives.  First, using a zero-width look-ahead assertion allows you to make the rest of the regex simpler:

```
/^[-+]?(?=\.?\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?$/
```

If you want to avoid the look-ahead, then I'd try to discourage the regex from back-tracking:

```
/^[-+]?(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d*)?)$/
/^[-+]?(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d*)?)$/ # if you don't mind capturing parens
```

Note that you said "base 10" so you might actually want to disallow extra leading zeros since "014" might be meant to be octal:

```
/^[-+]?(?:\.\d+|(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?)$/
/^[-+]?(\.\d+|(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d*)?)$/
```

Finally, you might want to replace `\d` with `[0-9]` since some regexes don't support `\d` or because some regexes allow `\d` to match Unicode "digits" other than 0..9 such as "ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT"s.

```
/^[-+]?(?:\.[0-9]+|(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]*)?)$/
/^[-+]?(\.[0-9]+|(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]*)?)$/
```

Comment: Tye, how would one do this from BASH? Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

Matches all specified examples, doesn't capture any groups:

```
^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$
```

To not match "1." (etc):

```
^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

Doesn't bother with whitespace (use a trim function).

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression in [perlfaq4: How do I determine whether a scalar is a number/whole/integer/float?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How_do_I_determine_w) does what you want, and it handles the "e" notation too.

```
while( <DATA> )
    {
    chomp;

    print /^([+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?$/ ?
        "$_ Works\n"
        :
        "$_ Fails\n"
        ;
    }

__DATA__
1
-1
- 3
1.2
1.2.3
7e4
.123
123.
.
-.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you are coding in this functionality may already exist.