# How can I test if a variable is *not* a positive integer?

Tags: bash

To test whether a variable is e.g. a number greater than 0, you would write:

```
((i > 0))
```

But how would I test if the variable is `not` a number greater than 0?

**EDIT**

Sorry for the typo, meant `not a number greater than 0`.

**EDIT 2**

Sry for the poor question. The value of the variable is passed as a commandline argument, so it may be a number or not. This also needs to be checked.

Comment: (!(i>10)) I dont remember the syntax but hope it helps

Comment: I think this question can be answered with just a bit of googling...

Comment: google -> "bash test comparison"

Comment: Who ever used `-gt`: That does not work in a general case to test if variable is number or not. It does not work because in aritmetic expressions, if a variable is not a number, it evaluates to 0

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down-voted. It is a valid question.

Comment: @CodeGnome: The title could be taken to imply validation.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Fair enough. The OP has updated his question to make the validation an explicit requirement, and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH: Test whether string is valid as an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For checking on not being number, you have to test with regex. I have used `-5` instead `0` just to demonstrate more general case (My assumption is that you use integers):

```
#!/bin/bash

A=$1

if [[ $A =~ ^[\-0-9]+$ ]] && (( A > -5)); then
  echo "A is number and is greater then -5"
else
  echo "A is not a number or is <= -5"
fi
```

If you want to test for non-integers, you have to clarify in your question what is considered number.

Comment: -1: using a regex is absolutely wrong.  `test` is designed specifically for this type of comparison, and using it will be less fragile, more readable, and faster.

Comment: The number literals in any programming language are defined in terms of "regular expressions". I dont see how that can be wrong.

Comment: It is wrong because explicitly testing if the number is greater than 0 is far more understandable than a regex string comparison, more efficient, and less prone to programming error.  Using `[[` instead of `test` forces you to make this string comparison, so the problem here is two-fold: `test` should be used instead of `[[` because using `[[` forces the regex comparison, which has no place here.

Answer (score 13):

```
i=15
if [[ ! $i -gt 10 ]]; then
        echo "lalala"
fi
```

Comment: @Achshar I disagree. Bash `[[` does not give an error. The script will return the result `lalala`.

Answer (score 5):

#### Comparisons

This is clearly covered in the Bash manual sections on [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) and [Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

```
# Shell arithmetic
$ (( -1 <= 0 )); echo $?
0

# Conditional expression
$ [[ -1 -le 0 ]]; echo $?
0

# Negated conditional. Confusing, but possible.
[[ ! -1 -gt 0 ]]; echo $?
0
```

Simple, right?

#### Validation

However, if you are trying to test whether or not the number is actually an integer before performing the comparsion, then you can use a compound expression like this to validate and compare a variable named *int*:

```
[[ "$int" =~ ^[-+]?([1-9][[:digit:]]*|0)$ && "$int" -le 0 ]]
```

Note that the comparison determines whether the validated integer is "less than or equal to zero," rather than negating the assertion that it is a positive integer. The entire expression will thus return true (e.g. an exit status of zero) only if the regular expression validates as a (possibly signed) integer *and* if the integer is a signed negative integer.

There are certainly other ways to construct this expression, but this is a fairly readable (if rather Bash-specific) solution.

#### Related Links

- [Bash: Testing if a variable is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623662/bash-testing-if-a-variable-is-an-integer)
- [How can I tell whether a variable contains a valid number?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/054)

Comment: `[^-]?` means an optional non-hyphen. You may have meant `^-?` which means an optional hyphen at the beginning of the string. While your `-gt` test indicates that your looking for a positive integer, your regex lacks generality since it excludes zero (while including positive and negative integers).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I appreciate the feedback. The entire expression actually had some inverted logic (now fixed), but the point is that the first half of the expression isn't intended to do anything other than validate "integerness." Admittedly, one could construct a regex that would replace both of the current validation and comparison steps (e.g. `^-[[:digit:]]+|^0$`), but I think that making the steps separate conveys the intent more clearly. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I realize this question is tagged bash, but there is no reason not to do this is a portable manner:

```
if ! test "$i" -gt 0 2> /dev/null ; then
   echo $i is not a positive integer
fi
```

Comment: +1. I still prefer using Bash constructs when Bash is explicitly mentioned, though. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simple regexes can allow non-numbers such as "11--22--99" (although they do evaluate mathematically inside the `(())`).

The following regex only allows 0 or negative integers without leading zeros and rejects negative zero.

```
for a in 0 -0 00 -1 -01 1 1-1 --1
do
    if [[ $a =~ ^(-[1-9][0-9]*|0)$ ]]
    then
        echo "[+] $a passes"
    else
        echo "[X] $a doesn't"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
[+] 0 passes
[X] -0 doesn't
[X] 00 doesn't
[+] -1 passes
[X] -01 doesn't
[X] 1 doesn't
[X] 1-1 doesn't
[X] --1 doesn't
```

At this point, you don't really need to add a test for `((a <= 0))` although you could test whether it was less than or equal to some smaller number.

**Edit:**

You could put the integer validation test in a function and do the comparison separately for readability like this:

```
isint () {
    [[ $1 =~ ^(-?[1-9][0-9]*|0)$ ]] # use [+-]? instead of -? to allow "+"
}

if isint "$var" && ((var <= 0))
then
    echo "validated and compared: $var"
else
    echo "non-integer or out of range: $var"
fi
```

Comment: I like the idea of extracting the regular expression test to a function. It certainly does make the conditional friendlier on the eyes. Thanks for posting a great alternate construction.