# How do I validate decimal numbers?

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I'm working on an assignment and got stuck on this part, how do I validate decimal numbers/numbers in shell?

It can accept numbers but not decimal numbers. I want it to be able to accept both.

This is what I have so far

```
if echo $value | egrep '^[0-9]+$' >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
echo "OK"
else
echo "There Is An Error"
echo "Please Try Again"
fi
```

Comment: `7` is a "decimal number".  `7.2` is also a "decimal number.  `7` is an integer.  `7.2` is a "non-integer".

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH: Test whether string is valid as an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using grep, you can use the bash to check expression:

```
#!/bin/bash

value=98.23
if [[ "$value" =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$ ]]
then
   echo good
else
   echo bad
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

use this regex instead   `^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried it by replacing it but it doesn't seem to work. It rejects all my input of letters, numbers and decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash's pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == ?([-+])+([0-9])?(.*([0-9])) ]] ||
       [[ $line == ?(?([-+])*([0-9])).+([0-9]) ]]
    then
        echo "$line is a number"
    else 
        echo "$line NOT a number"
    fi
done << END
1
-1
a
1a
1.0
1.
.0
.
-.0
+
+0
+.0
END
```

outputs

```
1 is a number
-1 is a number
a NOT a number
1a NOT a number
1.0 is a number
1. is a number
.0 is a number
. NOT a number
-.0 is a number
+ NOT a number
+0 is a number
+.0 is a number
```

The patterns:

- optional sign, followed by one or more digits, followed optionally by a dot and zero or more digits
- optional sign, followed by zero or more digits, followed by a mandatory dot, followed by one or more digits.

Comment: First one to notice possible occurence of positive/negative signing! <aybe one should even care about double/float representation in a mantissa/exponent way.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if [ ! -z $(echo "$value" | grep -o "^[1-9][0-9]*\.\?[0-9]*$") ]; then echo ok; fi
```

`-z` tests for an empty string. So the negation `[ ! -z "" ]` will be fulfilled if the given string starts with a matching pattern.

Comment: Hi J, thanks for your reply. I tried your code and it works but now it doesn't accept numbers, is there a way for it to do both?

Comment: Actually, it seems to work fine. Maybe you woule like to add some examples of input that you want to be accepted to your original question?

Answer (score 0):

In standard shell (`[[` is non-standard) `test` will do the validation for you.

```
if test "$value" -eq 0 -o "$value" -ne 0 2> /dev/null; then
  : # $value is an integer
else
  : # $value is not an integer
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It checks negative and decimal number also.

```
echo $value | egrep '^-[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+$|^[0-9].[0-9]+$|^-[0-9].[0-9]+$' > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in both Bash 3.0 and 4.0.

```
isInteger() {
    [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];
}
isDecimal() {
    [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]] && ! isInteger $1;
}

computer:~ # isDecimal 123 && echo true || echo false
false
computer:~ # isDecimal 12.34 && echo true || echo false
true
computer:~ # isDecimal 12.34a && echo true || echo false
false
computer:~ # isDecimal 0.0000001 && echo true || echo false
true
```

To check if number, simply test against both functions.