# Shell Scripting: RegEx in if Statement

Tags: regex, shell, if-statement

I can't seem to figure out how to write a regex correctly in an *if* statement. I wanted it to print out all the lines with "End Date" in it.

NUMBERS contains a text file with the following content:

```
End Date    ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC
05/15/13    2   7   1   1   4   5  
04/16/13    4   3   0   1   3   6  
03/17/13    6   9   3   8   5   9  
02/18/13    8   2   7   1   0   1  
01/19/13    1   9   2   2   5   2  
12/20/12    7   2   7   1   0   1
```

Here is a snippet of my code that I am having problems with:

```
if [ -f $NUMBERS ]
then
        while read line
        do
                if [ $line = ^End ]
                then
                        echo "$line"
                else
                        echo "BROKEN!"
                        break                   
                fi
        done < $NUMBERS
else
        echo "===== $NUMBERS failed to read  ====="
fi
```

The output is:

> Broken!

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for something this simple: `[[ $line == End* ]]`

Comment: Does your file actually contain the `>` characters at the start of each line?

Comment: @glennjackman I was doing the regex for the ones with dates, but it wasn't working, so I did it for the first line to make sure nothing was going wrong. The actual file does not contain the ">".

Answer (score 14):

if you're using **bash**, try `=~`:

```
...
if [[ $line =~ ^End ]]
```

Note that the following will NOT work:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes)

```
if [[ "$line" =~ "^End" ]]
```

Comment: Note that this is not portable to all shells.

Comment: @datguy What does "=~" do?

Comment: @dalawh `=~` tells bash to match against a regex instead of a literal string.

Answer (score 4):

The portable solution is to use `case` which supports wildcards (glob wildcards; not actual regular expressions) out if the box. The syntax is slightly freaky, but you get used to it.

```
while read -r line; do
    case $line in
        End*) ... your stuff here 
            ... more your stuff here
            ;;   # double semicolon closes branch
    esac
done
```

Comment: @cnst Indeed, this should be portable all the way back to the original Bourne `sh`. (No guarantees for `csh`, which some *BSD variants still - inexplicably - seem to cherish.)

Comment: Is it possible to use [0-9]* or equivalent? I want to check if the variable is 0 or positive integer.

Comment: @jimmymcheung Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/18620446/874188

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @tripleee , in the meantime, I found `[ -z "${inter##*[!0-9]*}" ]` would also work, never think of `##` in if statement!

Comment: while further viewing, I'm not sure now if `$##` is portable or is limited to bash. maybe I should still switch to `case`

Comment: The `##` parameter expansion should be reasonably portable, i.e. it's in POSIX but might not be supported by legacy shells like Solaris `sh`.  I really don't see how this discussion belongs here, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to check if the `line` begins with `End`

```
if [[ "$line" == End* ]]
```

You can use the following if you want to use regex.

```
if [[ "$line" =~ ^End* ]]
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Also note that it is recommended to always quote your variables.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: I thought there was no difference between = and ==. Is there? Also, what is the difference from using one [] and two []?

Comment: `if [ "$a" = "$b" ]` -- does a string comparison, but `==` with `[[ ]]` can be used for regex searching. Pls look at the link I gave in the answer. Hope it helps. Copied from that link -- `"The == comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets test than within single brackets."`

Comment: can you show me your code, it should work...i have tested it.

Comment: @dalawh I had a small typo. I updated the answer. Pls use `End*` and see if that works.

Comment: `[` is the basic old Bourne `sh` command `test` which does not support regex. The `[[` variant is a Bash (and `ksh` etc) extension with improved robustness around corner cases as well as more capabilities, including `=~` regex matching. The correct string equality operator is `=` though Bash leniently permits `==` as an alias.

Comment: The trailing asterisk in `^End*` is wrong; it says you want zero or more occurrences of `d` (and so the regex is equivalent to `^En`).