# bash integer number only

Tags: bash, integer, evaluation

I can't seem to allow single integer input only.
If someone puts abc, it will work.

But if someone puts in abc123 or 123abc it will still treat it as a valid integer

```
# input to be an integer.
validate_integer(){

    if [ !  "$#" -eq "1" ]; then
            error "Please enter one numberic value only"
            return 1
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ^[[:alpha:]]+$ ]]; then
            error "Input must be a NUMBER"
            return 1
    else
            return 0
    fi
}
```

Comment: Refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
elif [[ "$1" =~ ^[[:alpha:]]+$ ]]; then
```

to this:

```
elif ! [[ "$1" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
```

There, `^[[:digit:]]+$` means the string must be composed of digits from beginning to end, and it must be 1 or more characters long. We negate this with `!`, to handle the case when the string does not satisfy this condition (not fully numeric).