# Require integer input from user

Tags: shell, unix

I am adding two numbers using the below script, but I don't want non-numeric character entry from user so I need to test and throw an error.  How do I test the user entry?

```
echo add 2 numbers
read sum1
read sum2
let sum3=$sum1+$sum2
echo ans is $sum3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH: Test whether string is valid as an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` for testing if variable is valid integer:

```
isInt() {
    [[ -n "$1" ]] && printf '%f' "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 && 
                  echo "valid integer" || echo "invalid integer";
}
```

Comment: i used declare -i as below,<br>
<br>
`#/bin/bash<br>`
`echo integer testing;<br>`
`read no;<br>`
`declare -i iint=$no<br>`
`[ $iint = "$no" ] && echo "valid integer" || echo "invalid integer"\`<br>

<br>
it is not worked out for numeric with character inputs from user.<br>
<br>
integer testing<br>
2w<br>
int.sh: line 4: declare: 2w: value too great for base (error token is "2w")<br>
int.sh: line 5: [: =: unary operator expected<br>
invalid integer<br>
<br>
could you let me know how can resolve this?