# adb shell regular expression doesn't work as tested locally

Tags: android, regex, shell, adb, mksh

First, sorry if my question is obscure or in an inconvenient format. This is my first post here :D.

My issue is that I have a script, let's say `test.sh` which reads an input, and validates if it's a positive integer (reg ex used from this post:
[BASH: Test whether string is valid as an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer)):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n " enter number <"
read num

if [[ $num =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]     #if num contains any symbols/letters 
then                            # anywhere in the string
  echo "not a positive int"
  exit
else
  echo "positive int read"
fi
```

I am running this script on my android device (Xiaomi Mi3 w) using adb shell and the error:
syntax error: `=~` unexpected operator keeps displaying.

First, is my regex even correct? 
Second, any hints on how I can overcome this syntax error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30990219/1778421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use ksh expression as shown below to get this to work.

```
case $num in
    +([0-9])*(.)*([0-9]) )
          # Variable positive integer
      echo "positive integer"
          ;;
    *) 
          # Not a positive integer
      echo "NOPE"
      exit
          ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

The default shell in Android is [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm).  It is not 100% compatible with `bash`. So do not expect all `bash` recipes to work without changes.

For the description of features supported by `mksh` - read its [manual page](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm).

Comment: I tried using the manual, and I tried a few things but doesn't work. So far, the closest I got was :
if [ $num -gt 0]....

but this will accept values sch as  '-123' or '444a'. Any ideas? I tried using expressions such as 
$num -eq +[0-9] which I read in the manual, but it had worse results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a GNU bash POSIX regular expression. In Korn Shell, you can use extglob regular expressions to the same effect:

```
if [[ $num = ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]; then
    …
```

See the section “File name patterns” in the manpage for details.