# convert read string to integer in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read from user and then do the following.

```
read framechoice
 if [ $framechoice -gt 100 ]; then 
   if [ $framechoice -lt 0 ]; then
          framechoice=101
   fi
 fi
```

It gives me the following error.

> [: -gt: unary operator expected

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you don't input anything:

```
$ cat myscript
read framechoice
 if [ $framechoice -gt 100 ]; then
   if [ $framechoice -lt 0 ]; then
          framechoice=101
   fi
 fi
$ bash myscript
<enter>
myscript: line 2: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

Try instead to actually enter something:

```
$ bash myscript
42<enter>
```

The script then exits with success.

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs to cope with empty input.  This is most easily achieved by [properly quoting the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable); then

```
if [ "$framechoice" -gt 100 ]; then
```

evaluates to `[ "" -gt 100 ]` which is no longer is a syntax error; however, instead, it throws the warning `integer expression expected`.

Even better, maybe filter the input so that you do not attempt numeric comparisons before [making sure the input is numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer).