# Regex collating symbols

Tags: regex, bash

I tried to understand how 'collating symbols' match works but I did not come out this. I understood that it means matching an exact sequence instead of just the character(s), that is:

```
echo "ciiiao" | grep '[oa]'     --> output 'ciiiao'
echo "ciiiao" | grep '[[.oa.]]' --> no output
echo "ciiiao" | grep '[[.ia.]]' --> output 'ciiiao'
```

However, the third command does not work. Am I wrong or I misinterpret something?

I have read this regexp [tutorial](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html).

Comment: `[[.oa.]]` will throw "Invalid collation character" error. The double brackets is used in specific chars classes, like `[[:alpha:]]`. If you want the exact sequence, simply do `grep oa`.

Comment: So does `[[.ia.]]` when I use the C locale. Same with German locale, both the second and third commands fail. @MFrancone: what is your locale?

Comment: Collation is for sorting and is locale-defined. You can't just invent collation sequences on the fly like that. Specifically point 4 in the `RE Bracket Expression` section of the document you link to says "If the string is not a collating element in the current collating sequence definition, or if the collating element has no characters associated with it (for example, see the symbol <HIGH> in the example collation definition shown in Collation Order ), the symbol will be treated as an invalid expression.". So unless `oa`/`ia` are collating elements in your locale they are likely meaningless.

Comment: Thank you all, I supposed the use of collating symbols were different because I do not know the real meaning of 'locale'. I must figure it out firstly...where the collating symbols could be useful?

Answer (score 12):

Collating symbols are typically used when a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28orthography%29) is treated like a single character in a language. They are an element of the [POSIX regular expression specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html), and are not widely supported.

For example, [the Welsh alphabet has a number of digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_orthography) that are treated as a single letter (marked with a * below)

```
a b c ch d dd e f ff g ng h i j l ll m n o p ph r rh s t th u w y
       *           *    *          *          *    *      *
```

Assuming the locale file defines it (a collating symbol will only work if it is defined in the current [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale)), the collating symbol `[[.ng.]]` is treated like a single character. Likewise, a single character expression like `.` or `[^a]` will also match "ff" or "th." This also affects sorting, so that `[p-t]` will include the digraphs "ph" and "rh" in addition to the expected single letters.