# bash if structure in a for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create an exit error to expand on the previous script now. if I type anything but a number now and what I have tried so far is:

```
sum=0
for num in "$@"
do
echo $num | grep -i [^0-9+-]
if ["$?" = 1] then
echo "Sorry, '$num' is not a number"
fi

sum=$((sum + num))  
done
echo $sum
```

Example if I type in

```
add 1 2 3 four five
```

it would say

```
four
Sorry, 'four' is not a number
```

Comment: it's not clear at all what do you want to achieve. If a string that is not a number is passed you still count it as a number. Is it correct? Also $? = 1 is wrong. the correct syntax is $? -eq 1 but it's better to use $? -gt 0 it's more robust

Comment: @m47730 arguably it's better to use `if` with the command directly rather than using `$?` at all.

Comment: @TomFenech i agreed with you. I'm saying that it's better to use "-gt 0" instead "-eq 1"

Answer (score 1):

The following section of your code:

```
echo $num | grep -i [^0-9+-]
if ["$?" = 1] then
```

Should be changed to this:

```
if grep -q '[^0-9+-]' <<< "$num"; then
```

Inside a test (`[`), spaces are important but there's no need to use it here anyway. Using `-q` means that grep doesn't produce output - the exit status indicates whether a match was found or not, so it can be used directly with `if`.

As mentioned in the comments, the pattern to match a valid integer could be made more robust. Some good ways to detect an integer are shown in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2210349/2088135). For example, you could change your grep pattern to something like this:

```
grep -qE '^[+-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$'
```

or use native regular expressions, as in the most popular answer to that question:

```
re='^[+-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$'
if [[ $num =~ $re ]]; then
    sum=$((sum + num))
else
    echo "Sorry, '$num' is not a number"
fi
```

Even this pattern isn't perfect, as it will fail for numbers starting with leading `0`s, among other things.

Comment: also, you'd have to test about sole `-` in input. the regex would be slightly more complex.

Comment: @Jean-François it's a good point, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Note that `09` will cause an error in the addition as it will be interpreted as octal.

Comment: Nice catch @choroba, edited.

Comment: regex is a dead-end street in this  context. it's better to use "bc"

Comment: @m47730 can just do `((var)) || echo not number`, provided you accept equations as numbers.

Comment: @123 and accept only integers

Comment: @m47730 yes as op is using (()) for the addition anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No need to shell out. You can use extended pattern matching to verify the number format:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

sum=0
for num in "$@" ; do
    if [[ $num != @(0|?([-+])[1-9]*([0-9])) ]] ; then
        echo "Sorry, '$num' is not a number"
        exit 1
    fi
    (( sum += num ))
done
echo $sum
```

Note that `09` is not permitted, as it would be interpreted as octal and fail in addition:

```
value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

Comment: Or maybe simpler `[[ $num =~ ^[+-]?[0-9] ]]`.

Comment: @SLePort: That doesn't catch the `09`.

Comment: @SLePort: The correct regex is in the other answer. I just wanted to show that even regex is too strong here.

Comment: My bad, I did not read the discussion.