# How to check if a number is within a range in shell

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, sh

I want to just insert number between two values, and otherwise the script repeated until correct number.

This is my script and it does not work correctly:

```
validation(){
read number
if [ $number -ge 2 && $number -ls 5 ]; then
    echo "valid number"
    break
else
    echo "not valid number, try again"
fi

}

echo "insert number"
validation
echo "your number is" $number
```

Comment: Please mention your error or what issue you are getting while running this script.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are using Bash, you are better off using the arithmetic expression, `((...))` for readability and flexibility:

```
if ((number >= 2 && number <= 5)); then
  # your code
fi
```

To read in a loop until a valid number is entered:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
  read -p "Enter a number between 2 and 5: " number
  [[ $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Enter a valid number"; continue; }
  if ((number >= 2 && number <= 5)); then
    echo "valid number"
    break
  else
    echo "number out of range, try again"
  fi
done
```

`((number >= 2 && number <= 5))` can also be written as `((2 <= number <= 5))`.

---

See also:

- [Test whether string is a valid integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2210349/6862601)
- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188199/6862601)

Comment: Running `bash` `4.4-5` on Debian 9.8 here. `if ((2 <= 255 <= 254)); then echo 'true'; else echo 'false'; fi` returned `true`. And `if ((2 <= 255 && 255 <= 254)); then echo 'true'; else echo 'false'; fi` returned `false`.

Comment: One of my colleagues said `((2 <= number <= 5))` is evaluated as `((((2 <= number)) <= 5))` and that explained it. Brace expansion order is from left to right, as seen in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION

Comment: How to do this in single line, since I need it on a pipe to filter (URL) from `curl`  that had year at the end of it... this is my code curl -s  "$Url" -o - |awk '{print "http://web.archive.org/web/"$2"/"$1}' In short it's Archive.org `url` like this `http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=stackoverflow.com&fl=original,timestamp&matchType=prefix&limit=19&filter=statuscode:200&filter=mimetype:text/html`

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question, @Salem

Comment: ^^ sorry I'm restricted from asking more questions here, anyway I'll find the answer somewhere else.

Answer (score 12):

Your if statement:

```
if [ $number -ge 2 && $number -ls 5 ]; then
```

should be:

```
if [ "$number" -ge 2 ] && [ "$number" -le 5 ]; then
```

Changes made:

- Quoting variables is considered [good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable#comment71378550_10067297).
- `ls` is not a valid comparison operator, use `le`.
- Separate single-bracket conditional expressions with `&&`.

Also you need a shebang in the first line of your script: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: : : integer expression expected - You need to double up the brackets. I.e., [[ ]]

Answer (score 4):

```
if [ $number -ge 2 && $number -ls 5 ]; then
```

should be

```
if [[ $number -ge 2 && $number -le 5 ]]; then
```

see `help [[` for details

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code

```
echo "Enter number" 

read input

  if [[ $input ]] && [ $input -eq $input 2>/dev/null ]

  then

        if ((input >= 1 && input <= 4)); then

    echo "Access Granted..."

    break

  else

    echo "Wrong code"

  fi

  else

     echo "$input is not an integer or not defined"

  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

2 changes needed.

1. Suggested by Sergio.

   `if [ "$number" -ge 2 ] && [ "$number" -le 5 ]; then`
2. There is no need of `break`.  `only meaningful in a for, while, or until loop`

Answer (score 0):

while :; do
read option
if [[ $option -ge 1 && $option -lt 4 ]]; then
echo "correct"
c
break
else
echo "Incorrect option selected,choose an option between [1-4]"
fi
done