# Bash value between two integers, NOT floats

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this simple comparison operator, it check if `number` is between 1 and 3 (1 and 3 included too). But if I assign `number` to `3,2` it still accepts as correct.

It should only accept those values `1-2-3`

My code

```
if (("$number" >= 1 && "$number" <= 3)); then
echo 'Correct number'
fi
```

Comment: can you clarify that the assignment is really `number=1,2` and `number=3,2` Please put the assignment in you question/post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if [ "$number" -ge 1 ] && [ "$number" -le 3 ]; then 
echo 'Correct number'
fi
```

Comment: This will error-out when `number="3,2"`, with: `bash: [: 3,2: integer expression expected`. You have to check that `number` contains a valid integer.

Answer (score 6):

`(("$number" >= 1 && "$number" <= 3))` is a Bash's stand-alone arithmetic expression.

Within an arithmetic expression, variables are expanded as-is and if they contain valid arithmetic expression's syntax elements, these are also interpreted.

`number="3,2"` expands as `((3,2))` in an arithmetic expression, where comma `,` is interpreted as a statements separator by Bash's arithmetic expressions.

Lets see:

```sh
$ number="3,2"; echo "$((number))"
2
$ number="3+2"; echo "$((number))"
5
$ number="3*2"; echo "$((number))"
6
```

The shell only understands integer arithmetic, but `3,2` is not a valid integer value.

It means that if you are unsure a variable contains a valid integer, it is unsafe for use within an arithmetic expression.

Always check that `number` contains a valid integer (see: [Test whether string is a valid integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210386/7939871)) before using in an arithmetic expression or within a test comparing integers.

```sh
# Check number is a valid integer before testing its range.
[[ $number =~ ^[-+]?[0-9]+$ ]] && (("$number" >= 1 && "$number" <= 3))
```

The other numeric test method `[ "$number" -ge 1 ] && [ "$number" -le 3 ]` as suggested in the other answers will error-out with: `bash: [: 3,2: integer expression expected`.

It also needs testing for valid integer:

```sh
[[ $number =~ ^[-+]?[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$number" -ge 1 ] && [ "$number" -le 3 ]
```

With POSIX shell, there is no Regex test, so a different approach is needed:

```sh
case "${number#[+-]}" in(*[!0123456789]*|'')false;;esac &&
  [ "$number" -ge 1 ] && [ "$number" -le 3 ]
```

An additional note about the pitfalls of using arithmetic expressions to compare numbers. Arithmetic expressions will handle leading 0 of an integer, as an octal:

```sh
$ (( 13 >= 12 )); echo $?
0
```

but

```sh
$ (( 013 >= 12 )); echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to rewrite your code as follow:

```sh
if [ "$number" -ge 1 ] && [ "$number" -le 3 ]; then
    echo 'Correct number'
fi
```

Look at https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html for further information.