# Write a shell script which takes an input (an integer smaller than 10,000) from users and displays each digit of the integer one by one

Tags: shell

When input “153”, the shell script will identify and display “1”, “5” and “3” on the screen sequentially. If input “69”, it will display “6” and “9”.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe user input through `sed`:

```
echo $1 | sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash treats **everything** as a string.

Here is a Bash way to loop character by character over a string:

```
s=123
for (( i=0; i<${#s}; i++ )); do
    echo "${s:$i:1}"
done
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
```

Still for *you* to do:

1. Determine that `s` is a valid integer ([Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/test-whether-string-is-a-valid-integer))
2. Determine that `s` is a string representing less than 10,000? ([Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/how-can-i-compare-numbers-in-bash): inside of `(( double_parentesis ))` Bash treats those strings as integers)

Answer (score 0):

Does your `grep` support the `-o` option? Then

```
$ echo "153" | grep -o .
1
5
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="12345"

while IFS= read -n 1 char
do
    echo "$char"
# done <<< "$string"
done < <(echo -n "$string")
```

A here-string can be used instead of a `< <(echo -n ...)` construct if you do not care about a trailing newline.